# How to change root element name when using OpenCV FileStorage

Tags: xml, opencv, serialization

When saving data in xml format using OpenCV FileStorage, created xml has always root element with name opencv_storage. Can it be changed?

Comment: no. why do you even want this ?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether it can be done since I think it would be nice to have.